# Make part of UIImage transparent, or crop that region

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a UIImage like so:
[image]

I want to remove a rect in the middle to leave it like so:
[image]

Comment: Isnt convenient to add a UIView on top of your imageView?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The easiest way to punch a hole through would be to add a layer mask.

- `#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>`
- Create the path you want to clip (the rect you want to punch through)

  ```
  UIBezierPath *maskPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRect:yourView.bounds];
  [maskPath appendPath:[UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRect:rectToPunchThroughTheView]];
  ```
- Then create a mask layer and add it to your view - `CAShapeLayer` will allow you to define any path

  ```
  CAShapeLayer *maskLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];
  maskLayer.fillRule  = kCAFillRuleEvenOdd;
  maskLayer.fillColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
  maskLayer.path      = maskPath.CGPath;

  yourView.layer.mask = maskLayer;
  ```

Answer (score 2):

I would create a UIImage category and crop the image two times with different rects.

Here is the method I added yo my UIImage category a while ago that suited my needs good:

```
- (UIImage *)cropWithRect:(CGRect)rect {

    // If run on a retina device scale is 2 else 1
    rect = CGRectMake(rect.origin.x * self.scale,
                      rect.origin.y * self.scale,
                      rect.size.width * self.scale,
                      rect.size.height * self.scale);

    CGImageRef imgRf = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect(self.CGImage, rect);
    UIImage *croppedImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef 
                                                scale:self.scale
                                          orientation:self.imageOrientation];
    CGImageRelease(imageRef);

    return croppedImage;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this way

```
        CGRect fullimageRect;
        CGRect upperRect;
        CGRect lowerRect;

        UIImage *upperImage;
        UIImage *lowerImage;
        UIImage *finalImage;

        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(upperRect.size);
        [[UIImage imageNamed:@"yourimage.png"] drawInRect:lowerRect];
        upperImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext();


        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(lowerRect.size);
        [[UIImage imageNamed:@"yourimage.png"] drawInRect:lowerRect];
        lowerImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

        NSLog(@"%@",upperImage);
        NSLog(@"%@",lowerImage);


        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(fullimageRect.size);
        [upperImage drawInRect:upperRect];
        [lowerImage drawInRect:lowerRect];
        finalImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

        NSLog(@"%@",finalImage);
```